# backward sorting array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
    function apache($b) {
        return $b;
    }

    $a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    $num = "";

    foreach ($a as $b) {
        $num = apache($b) . $num ;
    }

    echo $num;
?>
```

When you write it like this the output is `654321`, but if you write it like this:

```
$num = $num . apache($b);
```

the output would be `123456`. I don't understand why the results are like that. Can someone explain this?

Comment: whats the point of the function `apache` as it just returns what was used to call it…

Comment: LOL, you are right I don't know why I did this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really hard to understand.
This line:

```
$num = apache($b) . $num;
```

add the currently selected number and appends the current value of `$num` to it. The result will be written to `$num`.
So this will happen:

```
$b.    $num = $num
1 .      "" = 1
2 .       1 = 21
3 .      21 = 321
4 .     321 = 4321
5 .    4321 = 54321
6 .   54321 = 654321
```

If you write

```
$num =  $num . apache($b);
```

instead, you're adding the currently selected number **behind** `$num`:

```
$num  .$b = $num
""    . 1 = 1
1     . 2 = 12
12    . 3 = 123
123   . 4 = 1234
1234  . 5 = 12345
12345 . 6 = 123456
```

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote? What should be improved?

Comment: it's been said that "if you aren't a flower don't be thorn" I don't know why people downvote

Comment: There are some good reasons for downvoting, but "he/she" should leave a comment, if the "current" reason is not an obvious one.

Answer (score 0):

one way you are appending to the string
the other way you are prepending to the string

which gives the effect of reversing it.

first way kind of looks like this

```
[1]
2[1]
3[21]
4[321]
5[4321]
6[54321]
```

the other way looks like this

```
[1]
[1]2
[12]3
[123]4
[1234]5
[12345]6
```

where the value outside the [] is the value being returned by your function and the value inside the [] is $num